# Using different values for constants in development and live Android builds

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm quite sure this question has been asked before but I cannot for the life of me find it.

I am working on a simple Android app and there are a couple of things I'd like to have appear differently in "dev" and "live" builds. These are:

1. An XML constant
2. A code constant
3. A button's visibility state (ideally in the layout XML)

What I would really love is to never have to switch between dev and live states anywhere - when I run the thing in Eclipse I get the dev state, and when I click File..Export to make an APK I get the live state.

Is this something that's even possible with Eclipse? I've seen lots of solutions that involve installing extra tools or running batch scripts but frankly if it's going to be that complicated I'll just carry on changing them manually.

Comment: The new Gradle-based build system handles this, though that is still a work in progress at the present time.

Answer (score 1):

One of the steps you take when exporting to .apk is signing your code, yes?  So what you need is a means to determine whether your code has actually been signed with a release key (.apk) vs. a debug key (dev version).

Take a look [here](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com/2011/04/detecting-keystore-signature-in-code.html).

Comment: Installing an Android app to a device or emulator requires the APK to be signed **period**. The difference is whether you sign it with a personal key or with the debug key.

Comment: Edited.  I should proofread more, but this episode of Mad Men is rather compelling. :P

Comment: It does seem that I can do if(Build.FINGERPRINT.contains("generic")) to see if it's a debug build... but I'm not 100% sure whether this is reliable or not. The documentation for Build.FINGERPRINT specifically tells me not to parse it. :)

Comment: @ChrisR I believe that the link given in this answer is more reliable than using `Build.FINGERPRINT` or any of the other fields from `Build`.